# Text colour issue when searching

Tags: bug, status-completed, color

When searching for questions, the colour of the text which shows the number of votes for accepted answers [appears to be wrong](https://superuser.com/search?q=user:1931+[windows]):

[image: https://superuser.com/search?q=user:1931+[windows]]

Presumably the text should be the same colour as the "votes" text. This problem [doesn't seem to occur on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:22656+[c%23]).

Comment: Same here, not on front page or anything though, only at search.

Comment: Have you cleared you cache?

Comment: @random Yes, and tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number will be white after the next build; that's indeed a tiny bit more readable :) Thanks!